# How to upgrade Apache POI version in Alfresco 5.2. project?

Tags: maven, alfresco

I have Alfresco 5.2 project with Apache POI version "3.10.1-20151016-alfresco-patched" and I need to update in up to 5.0.0 version.
I have add the section

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

But as I can see the class XWPFTableCell still has an old version: /home/katya3/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.10.1-20151016-alfresco-patched/poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20151016-alfresco-patched-sources.jar!/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.java
Also I can not see the required method setWidth (added in 4.0.0) so the version is still old. Please teach me how to upgrade?
Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to manually remove the old jars, but also recompile the bits of Alfresco that deal with Apache POI for the changes to POI from the latest 6 years

Comment: recompile Alfresco? Could you provide more details?

Comment: This seems like a road to ruin. Why can't you stick with the shipped version? If you need to use a different POI version because there is some feature you need, write a completely separate service that depends on the newer version and invoke it remotely from Alfresco rather than changing the low-level components that ship with the product.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, problem was solved upgrading Alfresco to version 6.2

Answer (score 1):

Current Alfresco supported Poi version is 4.1.2. Use this version and do a maven clean and install, it will work.

```
<dependency.poi.version>4.1.2</dependency.poi.version>
```